# pgBouncer configuration error using Postgres

Tags: postgresql-9.1, pgbouncer

When I connect pgBouncer to Postgres using the configuration file pgbouncer.ini, it shows an error as

> client login timeout < server down>

What is the problem?

Comment: I would say your Postgres server is not running or your pgBouncer configuration is wrong.

Comment: Ok sir... But it asks for password ... if i give wrong password it tells password is wrong ... when i give right password it takes 20 to 30 seconds and then shows client login timeout <server down>.... Actually postgresql is running ..